# How to obtain success rate (accuracy) from KNeighboorsRegressor (scikit-learn)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
import pandas
with open('aotiz.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    aotiz = pandas.read_csv(csvfile)


test = aotiz.loc[16:7000]
# Generate the train set with the rest of the data.
train = aotiz.loc[7000:7006]

x_columns = distance_columns
y_column = ["PM2.5"]

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn import metrics

knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=6)
# Fit the model on the training data.
knn.fit(train[x_columns], train[y_column])
# Make point predictions on the test set using the fit model.
predictions = knn.predict(test[x_columns])

actual = test[y_column]

mse = (((predictions - actual) ** 2).sum()) / len(predictions)

print(mse)
```

I'm trying to know how to get the accuracy of this model from `scikit-learn`. For the moment I could only get the mean squared error, but how do I compare the 'actual' and the 'predictions' sets to see with the percentage the error that I have from the 'actual' list.

Comment: Use one of the [regression-metrics](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#regression-metrics). You could also define threshold / delta and consider predictions to be correct if: `abs(y_true -
 y_pred) < delta` - this will return booleans (i.e. we will convert regression task into classification task), so we can easily calculate the accuracy...

Comment: I assume you know that accuracy is never used as a performance metric in regression settings...